# XSL Transformation from input XML to an Output XML

Tags: xml, xslt, input, output, transform

I have an Input XML which need to transformed to another XML structure using XSLT. Can someone please help me out. I tried understanding XSL tutorials but this looks little complex to handle.

I need to convert the root node as Entity and where ever a node with attribute type exists, the text value of such node need to be mapped to a new attribute ID. Also the name attribute of such nodes need to be renamed as lookupAttr. Thanks a ton in advance.

Input XML

```
 <xml-fragment type="salesorder">
  <customerid name="bppartnerid" type="account">120100</customerid>
  <freightamount>0.000</freightamount>
  <orderreference/>
  <signatureid name="signaturecode" type="signature">CHRHUG</signatureid>
  <termsofpaymentid name="termsofpaymentcode" type="termsofpayment">30</termsofpaymentid>
  <name>ordernumber#E1ORNO</name>
  <ordernumber>10440</ordernumber>
  <pricelevelid name="name" type="pricelevel">01 GBP</pricelevelid>
  <transactioncurrencyid name="isocurrencycode" type="transactioncurrency">GBP</transactioncurrencyid>
</xml-fragment>
```

OutputXML

```
<Entity type="salesorder">

  <customerid lookupAttr="bppartnerid" type="account" id= "120100"></customerid>
  <freightamount>0.000</freightamount>
  <orderreference/>
  <signatureid lookupAttr="signaturecode" type="signature" id="CHRHUG"/>
  <termsofpaymentid lookupAttr="termsofpaymentcode" type="termsofpayment" id="30"></termsofpaymentid>
  <ordernumber>10440</ordernumber>
  <pricelevelid lookupAttr="name" type="pricelevel" id="01 GBP"></pricelevelid>
  <transactioncurrencyid lookupAttr="isocurrencycode" type="transactioncurrency" id="GBP"></transactioncurrencyid>

</Entity>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I think you misunderstood the purpose of this site. People are not here to do your work. We expect you to show that you have familiarized yourself with the problem, then made an attempt to solve it. In short: Write XSLT code first, ask afterwards.

Comment: As a starter, read-up on the XSLT identity transform. Using that you then only need to write templates for the nodes and attributes you wish to change. Try this site for example: http://www.xmlplease.com/xsltidentity

Answer (score 0):

Here you have an example which should get you on your way;

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8"/>
    <xsl:template match="xml-fragment">
        <Entity>
            <xsl:attribute name="type">
                <xsl:value-of select="@type"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <customerid>
                <xsl:attribute name="lookupAttr">
                    <xsl:value-of select="customerid/@name"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="type">
                    <xsl:value-of select="customerid/@type"/>
                </xsl:attribute>        
                <xsl:value-of select="customerid"/>
            </customerid>
            <freightamount>
                <xsl:value-of select="freightamount"/>
            </freightamount>
        </Entity>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```